# (Apollo) GraphQL Merging schema

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am using GraphQL tools/libraries offered by Apollo.

**It is possible to merge remote GraphQL schema into a nested structure?**

Assume I have `n` remote schemas, and I would like to merge the `Query`, `Mutation` and `Subscription` from different schemas into a single schema, except, each remote schema is placed under their own `type`.

Assume we have a remote schema called `MenuX` with:

```
type Item {
  id: Int!
  description: String
  cost: Int
}

type Query {
  items: [Item]
}
```

and a remote schema called `MenuY` with:

```
type Item {
  id: Int!
  name: String
  cost: Int
}

type Query {
  items: [Item]
}
```

I would like to merge the schema into a single schema but under their own types. A contrived example:

```
type MenuXItem {
  id: Int!
  description: String
  cost: Int
}

type MenuYItem {
  id: Int!
  name: String
  cost: Int
}

type MenuXQuery {
  items: [MenuXItem]
}

type MenuYQuery {
  items: [MenuYItem]
}

type Query {
  MenuX: MenuXItem
  MenuY: MenuYItem
}
```

As we can see that under the `Query` type it contains two new types which contain the query type from the remote schemas. `Item` from schema `MenuX` have been renamed by using the transformers from `graphql-tools`, similarly `Item` from schema `MenuY` has been transformed as well.

But is it possible to transform the structure as well?

With the actual remote schemas, we are looking at hundreds of types from each schema, and ideally, I would like to not pollute the root types and the Introspection documentation in GraphiQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin for Gatsby that contains a transformer that does what you want: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-graphql/src/transforms.js

It namespaces the types of an existing GraphQL schema, so that you end up with:

```
type Namespace1Item {
    ...
}

type Namespace2Item {
    ...
}

type Namespace1Query {
    items: [Namespace1Item]
}

type Namespace2Query {
    items: [Namespace2Item]
}

type Query {
    namespace1: Namespace1Query
    namespace2: Namespace2Query
}
```

So, if you transform your schemas and them merge them, you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

Apollo's graphql-tools includes a module to [transform schemas](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-transforms.html).  You should be able to rename everything in `MenuX` with something like

```
import {
  makeRemoteExecutableSchema,
  transformSchema,
  RenameTypes
} from 'graphql-tools';
const schema = makeRemoteExecutableSchema(...);
const menuXSchema = transformSchema(schema, [
  RenameTypes((name) => `MenuX${name}`)
]);
```

Then you can [use the transformed schema](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-stitching.html#using-with-transforms) as the input to `mergeSchemas`.

Note that the top-level `Query` and `Mutation` types are somewhat special and you may want to try to more directly merge those types without renaming them, particularly if they don't conflict.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer the question of "It is possible to merge remote GraphQL schema into a nested structure?" The transforms are great for everything under the root (query, mutation, subscription), but I want to transform those into a nest structure as well.

Comment: (TFM says “Root objects are never renamed by this transform”, and you did explicitly ask that.)

Comment: Unless I am missing something, renaming a field is not the same as nesting it under a new part item. Everywhere I look, renaming fields to add a prefix to the _name_ is the example, but not nesting a remote schema under a new parent. This is desirable, so as to not pollute the root level. Any ideas there?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to achieve schema where `Query` type has root fields as entry points into source schemas, but only for `Query` type as `Mutation` type doesn't support nesting of mutations under names.

For this reason, prefixing names is prefered solution for schema stitching.